# How to execute Javascript inside jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, dom, xss

I have a code like this:

```
$('.' + InjectionPoint).removeClass('classname');
```

where `InjectionPoint` is the part controlled by end user, apparently this code is vulnerable to [DOM XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS), but is it really exploitable? and how should an attack vector be like?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On what are you basing your belief that "this code is vulnerable to DOM XSS"?

Based on this answer, that was true in older versions of jQuery, but not any version later than 1.6.3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11170073/877682

Comment: It was a web security scanner that reported that issue, but I think you are right that it's not exploitable, but aren't there a way to evaluate expressions inside the selector, even just for development purposes

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely subject to XSS. Check out this article which describes how an attacker might go about it: https://ttmm.io/tech/jquery-xss/

Basically, the author recommends that you use document.querySelectorAll() instead of the jQuery selector function. Someone commented that this is a non-issue for jQuery 1.7 and above but don't quote me on that.

In general, it's never ever a good idea to trust what your users give you.