# Sanitize jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, security, selector, sanitize

Is it safe to use user input in a jQuery element selector like this:

```
$(".only-show-for-mode-" + mode).removeClass("hidden")
```

If `mode` came from user input or the http query?

Comment: I think the worst it can do is to throw an error when no element matches...

Comment: Which you could mitigate with a `try { $(".only-show-for-mode-" + mode).length } catch { alert("nope, not gonna work"); }` (which is different from not finding anything)

Comment: You also might like to make it more specific, eg `$(".container .only-show-for-mode-" + mode).show();`

Comment: If appropriate, you might consider checking that the value exists in a predefined list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can malicious javascript code be injected through $()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169894/can-malicious-javascript-code-be-injected-through)