# How to select dynamic value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have very funny situation that I can not solve. I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="pp227">
  <span>Funny text</span>
</div>
```

Note: this `pp` can have value from **0 - 500** and this structure need to says as it is. 
I end up with jQuery code like this:

```
var selectText = $('.pp[0] > span');
```

Can anybody have an idea how can I select this value from `pp`

Comment: on which event you are trying to read the value of pp? are you trying to read values of all pp elements?

Answer (score 3):

You can select an element based on one part of an attribute - in this case, the start of the class.

So this will work:

```
[class^='pp'] > span
```

Also to get the actual text (as opposed to just a jQuery object containing a reference to the selected element(s), you need to use the `.text()` function.

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  var selectText = $("[class^='pp'] > span").text();
  console.log(selectText);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pp227">
  <span>Funny text</span>
</div>
```

Note that this assumes you only ever have one element with a class starting with "pp" in the page at a time. If not, and you want to get the text of all them, then you'll need a loop. You didn't really clarify this in the question.

See https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/ for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this wildcard pattern to select elements & then loop through all to get className & value like this,

```js
$("[class^=pp]").each(function(){
  let my_class = $(this).attr('class');
  console.log("Class > ",my_class," Val > ",$(this).find('span').html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pp227">
  <span>Funny text 1</span>
</div>
<div class="pp226">
  <span>Funny text 2</span>
</div>
<div class="pp225">
  <span>Funny text 3</span>
</div>
<div class="pp224">
  <span>Funny text 4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given there's a variable called `index` that contains the number:

```
var myIndex = 117;
```

You do a string concatenation:

```
$('.pp' + +myIndex + ' > span')
```

**NOTE: the unary `+` operator is there to enforce integral value and prevent [jQuery injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169894/can-malicious-javascript-code-be-injected-through).**

Comment: Correct me if I've misunderstood, but as far as I can see, per the article you linked to, the string would be safe from injection attacks even without the extra + operator, because any script placed in the myIndex variable would be interpreted as a CSS selector, not executable code.

Comment: @ADyson didn't look throughly in the post tbh. better safe than sorry tho ;)

Comment: Fair enough. Also the issue in the original question is based on what is now a very old version of jQuery, and the answer mentions that the vulnerability is fixed in 1.9 onwards (which itself is very old now too)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the array is similar to `var pp = [52,356,12,152,...,398];`

```
var selectText = $('.'+pp[0]+' > span');
```

Javascript allows concatenation between `string` and `int` values.

Concatenation is donde with the `+` operator.